# Create an array of dates based on the input dates

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have a JSON payload as:

```
{
    "start_date": "20210314",
    "end_date": "20210613"
}
```

I want to get an array in such a way that it contains:

```
[
  {
    "start_date": "20210314",
    "end_date": "20210404"
  },
  {
     "start_date": "20210405",
     "end_date": "20210426"
  },
  {
     "start_date": "20210427",
     "end_date": "20210518"
  }.... till the end date in JSON payload
]
```

The **start_date** and **end_date** are already coerced in **date** format.
The gap in each object's dates are **21 days**
I am creating a REST API in **mule 4**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of [Period](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#dw_type_dates_period) and math operators should get you to the desired result.

**Input**

```
{
    "start_date": "20210314",
    "end_date": "20210824"
}
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var days=(payload.end_date as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"} - payload.start_date as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"}) as Number {"unit": "days"}
---
1 to ceil(days/21) map {
    start_date:if(($$)==0)(payload.start_date) else (payload.start_date as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"} + (("P"++(21*($$)+($$))++"D") as Period )) as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"},
    end_date: if(($$)==0)((payload.start_date as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"} + |P21D|) as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"}) 
   
     else if (((payload.end_date as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"}) -((payload.start_date as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"} + (("P"++(21*($$) +21+($$))++"D") as Period )) as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"})) as Number {"unit" : "days"} < 0) payload.end_date
    
    else (payload.start_date as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"} + (("P"++(21*($$) +21+ ($$))++"D") as Period )) as Date {"format": "uuuuMMdd"}
}
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "start_date": "20210314",
    "end_date": "20210404"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "20210405",
    "end_date": "20210426"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "20210427",
    "end_date": "20210518"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "20210519",
    "end_date": "20210609"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "20210610",
    "end_date": "20210701"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "20210702",
    "end_date": "20210723"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "20210724",
    "end_date": "20210814"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "20210815",
    "end_date": "20210824"
  }
]
```